How to improve OCR extraction from low-contrast and blurred newspaper images using Python and Tesseract?
I am working on a Django application to extract text from images of newspaper clippings. These images often have low contrast and blurring, and contain various text blocks such as headings, dates, small text, bold text, and some blurred letters. The images have dimensions of approximately 256x350 pixels with a resolution of 96 dpi.
I have tried multiple preprocessing techniques to enhance the images before feeding them to Tesseract OCR, but I am still not getting satisfactory results. Here is my current code:
import os
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import pytesseract
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import re

# Set Tesseract command
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/bin/tesseract'

def clean_text(text):
    # Example of cleaning common OCR errors
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)  # Remove extra whitespace
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s,.!?;:()"\']', '', text)  # Keep common punctuation
    return text.strip()

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'layout/index.html')

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if image is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Error loading image: {image_path}")
    
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Histogram equalization to enhance contrast
    gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
    
    # Increase contrast further if necessary
    gray = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gray, alpha=2.5, beta=50)
    
    # Resize the image to increase readability (aggressively)
    height, width = gray.shape
    scale_factor = 2  # Increase the scale factor for more aggressive resizing
    new_width = int(width * scale_factor)
    new_height = int(height * scale_factor)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(gray, (new_width, new_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    
    # Apply Gaussian Blur to remove noise
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_image, (3, 3), 0)
    
    # Apply adaptive thresholding and combine with Otsu's method
    _, binary_otsu = cv2.threshold(blurred_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    binary_adaptive = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    
    # Combine the results
    binary = cv2.bitwise_and(binary_adaptive, binary_otsu)
    
    # Sharpen the image
    kernel_sharpening = np.array([[0, -1, 0], 
                                  [-1, 5, -1],
                                  [0, -1, 0]])
    binary = cv2.filter2D(binary, -1, kernel_sharpening)
    
    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove noise
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    binary = cv2.dilate(binary, kernel, iterations=1)
    binary = cv2.erode(binary, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    return binary

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('document'):
        document = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(document.name, document)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

        # Preprocess the uploaded document
        try:
            preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(fs.path(filename))
        except ValueError as e:
            return render(request, 'layout/index.html', {'error': str(e)})

        # Convert the processed image to PIL format
        preprocessed_image_pil = Image.fromarray(preprocessed_image)

        # Extract text using Tesseract
        custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 12 --dpi 1500'
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(preprocessed_image_pil, config=custom_config)

        # Clean the extracted text
        text = clean_text(text)

        context = {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,
            'text': text,
        }
        return render(request, 'layout/index.html', context)
    return render(request, 'layout/index.html')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document Layout Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Document</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'upload' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="document">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    {% if uploaded_file_url %}
        <h2>Uploaded Document:</h2>
        <img src="{{ uploaded_file_url }}" alt="Document">
        <h2>Extracted Text:</h2>
        <pre>{{ text }}</pre>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns are [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
]


It is a reasonable heuristic that most of the paper of a printed document is sort of white (or for old material yellow with orange spots). For this reason if you have a colour scan available then the red channel alone is often a much better higher contrast starting point. Always worth a look at the green but the blue channel usually just adds noise and foxing marks and lowers contrast.
To make text more readable "equalise histogram" isn't really what you want to do to the monochrome image. What you actually want to do is smash all the histogram peak at the top end near white to 255 and the smaller peak at the bottom end to 0 and then linearly assign the  N remaining intervening values to (255*k)/N. Exact choice of cutoff isn't sensitive but this step wrecks halftone images to make the text contrast more clear.
If that still isn't enough and the text remains blurred then unsharp masking matched to the blur determined empirically from the image usually works best rather than a crude "sharpen" kernel.
You should be able to avoid having to Gaussian blur the image entirely (a step which is only needed in your workflow because of the side effects of equalise histogram). If it does need any further noise pre treatment remove salt and pepper noise or a median filter or edge preserving smooth are all better choices.
Gaussian blur can help make scanned halftone images into something acceptable though.
Sometimes one method of denoising works much better than any of the others on a particularly messy page that has been through the wars. The workflow above should work reasonably well on most material but a few awkward cases will need additional manual intervention to get the best results.

but in my code where i have to make changes i cants understand

Experiment with your actual images in an image processing app like Gimp or PSPro to perfect the method that works best for your scans to isolate clear text. It makes no sense to try and automate the workflow in code until you have one that is effective.
